# Using MATLAB to invoke an Octave model

Tags: matlab, octave

I am running an optimization code in MATLAB that requires a fitness value from a model that is Octave compatible (I cannot use MATLAB to solve this model. Hence Octave.). In order to do so I have written a fitness function in MATLAB that looks like this

```
fid = fopen('parameter.txt','w');
for i=1:length(x)
%    fprintf(fid,'%e \n',x(i));
    fprintf(fid,'%12.5f \n',x(i));
end
fclose(fid);

system('./dswrap');

% get the objective fitness value:
fid = fopen('fitness.txt','r');
y=fscanf(fid,'%f',[1]);
fclose(fid);
```

1. x is an input vector for the model that goes into parameter.txt
2. fitness.txt is the output from ./dswrap

dswrap is a code that is written in C that looks as follows

```
int main()
    {
        FILE*fp,*fp_r;
        fp=popen("octave","w");
        fprintf(fp,"ObjFuS");
        pclose(fp);
    }
```

This invokes octave and thereafter calls ObjFus that takes input from parameter.txt and outputs to fitness.txt. The problem I am facing is fitness.txt does not get generated and after some amount of twiddling I see one problem as

```
sh: octave: command not found
```

I can invoke octave from my terminal. So I am unsure as to why I am getting the above error?
Would it be that I am doing something else incorrectly. I need help with regards to generating my fitness.txt correctly. Thanks.

Comment: Why are you using c-code to run octave instead of running octave directly from matlab via system command?

Comment: Can you use [system](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/matlab/ref/system.html) command?

Comment: @Marcin Yes I am able to use system command

Comment: @Daniel I am not very familiar with MATLAB. I tried doing the following `system('octave ObjFuS')`. This did not work. I got the following - `/bin/bash: octave: command not found`. So I used a C wrapper hoping that I can invoke octave through C which again did not work.

Comment: I must admit that seeing you use Matlab to call C to call Octave made me laugh. Just curious, but why can't you do the solving in matlab directly?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your system needs more information than just the name of the program to start it. Calling it from a different language won't help, but fortunately specifying the path will.

For me the following call fails:

```
!textpad % Equivalent to system('textpad')
```

But this one works:

```
!"C:\Program Files (x86)\TextPad 6\TextPad.exe"
```